# Passing Arguments to JNLP from a JSP

Tags: java, arguments, parameter-passing, java-web-start, jnlp

I'm working on replacing an applet with an application launched with Java Web Start. So far in my demo version developed in Netbeans, I'm able to generate the `launch.jnlp` with the arguments set to the desired values:

```
<application-desc main-class="myPkg.MyClass">
    <argument>action=someAction</argument>
    <argument>objId=1234abc</argument>
    <argument>userName=user1</argument>       
</application-desc>
```

But what this JWS-launched application has to do in real life is to set the arguments in the JNLP based on the values selected by and related to the user of the web application that would launch it.

I realize this question has been asked before, but in most cases several years have passed since those questions were answered and I am unsure if the answers are still applicable, given the security lockdown that Java has been put through by the browser vendors. Is the way to accomplish this these days to send the argument values via HTTP request parameters, i.e.,

`[codebase]/launch.jnlp?action=someAction&objId=1234abc&userName=user1` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While my implementation is still a work in progress, I did want to say that what's working for me so far is to create the JNLP dynamically within a servlet, writing it out to a stream associated with an HTTPResponse object...

Answer (score 0):

You can pass parameters to an applet started via JWS just as you can when starting an applet in the browser, e.g. in the JNLP. However, you must build the JNLP containing these server-side AFAIK; passing them as URL-Args directly to javaws is not possible (the URL only makes the browser download the jnlp and throw it at javaws's feet, and that again would fetch it from the server possibly **again**, so be sure to build the

`<jnlp codebase="http://@JAVA_WEB_START_IP@"`**href="**`/launch.jnlp?action=someAction&objId=1234abc&userName=user1`**"**

so that it matches the parameters with which you invoke the jnlp "cgi"

So you need a cgi named launch.jnlp putting the parameters into a jnlp template

1) at the href as url parameters

2) in the applet-desc

```
 <applet-desc main-class="com.xyz.class" 
  width="850" height="650" name="Applet Name">
   <param name="action" value="someAction"/>
   <param name="objId" value="1234abc"/>
   <param name="userName" value="user1"/>
 </applet-desc>
```

At least this is the possibility I'm aware of and that works for me.

**Edit**

Same applies if you are using an `application-desc` instead, then instead of the `<param`s you have to fill the `<argument`s accordingly, besides the href...

Comment: I'm trying to avoid using the `applet` tag, since I hear it will not be supported in Java 1.9, which is due out in September. Is there a way to build `launch.jnlp` dynamically so that the argument values can be specified at runtime?

Comment: Who is talking about applet-tag? Did you read my answer or only try to understand as few words as possible?

Comment: I was referring to your use of the `applet-desc' tag, since I've been using `application-desc`. Maybe it doesn't make a difference, but, either way, is there any reason for you to be so sarcastic in your response? Clearly I'm new to using JNLP, since I'm asking questions about it, so I don't see why you felt the need to go that route...

Comment: I see. I apologize for being offensive. That does make a difference indeed - when you use `application-desc` then jawaws expects an application, i.e. a normal executable jar. So if your jar contains an applet, i.e. if you main class extends java.applet.Applet or javax.swing.JApplet, you do have to use `applet-desc`. But the answer applies as well if you use application-desc, then you have to fill the `<argument>`s accordingly. javaws as it seems will still be able to launch applets even after the browser plugin will be gone.

Comment: Thanks for the apology, Stefan; I'm a little weary of online sarcasm from strangers these days :) Since I won't know ahead of time what the argument values will be, doesn't that mean I'll have something like EL variables and the JNLP in a JSP page to build it dynamically?

Comment: Well, sorry, can't help you about JSP, I had build mine jnlp inside a C program, and I had only to evaluate the http Host: header (on an appliance). So I don't understand what EL could mean. But in general the approach is to use a jnlp template and fill in the bits.

Comment: EL stands for Expression Language, used to represent values passed to JSP pages these days. Thanks for your responses...